# Best Way to Add Implied Multiplication (*) to a Python String?

Tags: python, regex, string

I know how to do this in other languages that are stronger with RegEx, but I'm not sure about Python. Basically what I'm trying to do is convert

```
(30(5-10x))+10=20
```

into

```
(30*(5-10x))+10=20
```

And it would also be nice to add

```
(30*(5-10*x))+10=20
```

if the x is preceded by a number.

In Perl, the regex would look something like

```
/ \w+\K (?=\() | \)\K (?=\w) | \)\K (?=\() /*/
```

And to take care of the x's:

```
/\d\K(?=[x])/*/
```

How is this best done in Python?

Comment: What else can you have? Just a few examples: `2x^2`, `1/2x`, `x(x+1)`, `2sinx`, `2sin^2x`, `0.123exp12`, `exp(0.123,12)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like it better like Nate did, i.e., just add the `*`, not take the surrounding characters out only to put them back in.

```
>>> e = '(1+2)(30(5-10x))x+10=20'
>>> re.sub('(?<=\w|\))(?=\() | (?<=\))(?=\w) | (?<=\d)(?=x)', '*', e, flags=re.X)
'(1+2)*(30*(5-10*x))*x+10=20'
```

The three parts are *"before ("*, *"after )"*, and *"between digit and x"*. Could maybe be combined, but then we might combine too much, so I find it clearer and safer this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for your example, and adapt it accordingly for strings like `(x+2)10` if you need:

```
import re

s = '(30(5-10x))+10=20'

r = re.sub(r'(\d)([(a-zA-Z])', r'\1*\2', s)

print(r)   # Prints (30*(5-10*x))+10=20
```

**Short explanation**:
The capturing groups `\1` and `\2` are substituted with ... the same capturing groups and an additional `*` in between them.

<sub>(Code improvements by [@shashank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2653390/shashank))</sub>

Comment: You're not handling the `\)\K (?=\w) | \)\K (?=\() /*/` part, though.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I don't know Perl so I don't understand that regex. But if you're talking bout inserting * after closed parentheses, this can easily be modified to `re.sub(r'([\d)])([(A-Za-z])', r'\1*\2', s)`. This turns `'(1+2)(30(5-10x))x+10=20'` into `'(1+2)*(30*(5-10*x))*x+10=20'`

Comment: I found another case, a variable before a parentheses like `'x(4y)z'` can't be handled currently. This managed to fix it: `re.sub(r'([\d)]|\w(?=\())([(A-Za-z])', r'\1*\2', 'x(4y)z')`

Comment: Yes, `*` after `)`. Including turning `'(1+2)3' into '(1+2)*3'.

Comment: @Shashank I agree, but my intention is to give a solution that the asker can easily adapt to all his needs, not provide a ready to copy-paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

I only try to translate your regular expressions, such that they do not use `\K`.

You could achieve this by matching the preceeding characters also, and use them in the replacement as backreference.

```
/ \w+\K (?=\() | \)\K (?=\w) | \)\K (?=\() /*/

becomes 

re.sub(r'(\w+(?=\()|\)(?=\w)|\)(?=\())', r'\\1*', original )
```

And to take care of the x's:

```
/\d\K(?=[x])/*/
```

becomes

```
re.sub(r'(\d(?=[x]))', r'\\1*', original)
```

Notes :

- I removed the spaces, I suppose you added them for legibility.
- I don't think your perl regex is specific enough. For instance it will transform `sin(x)` into `sin*(x)`.

Comment: This gives me stuff like `'(1+2\x00*(\x00*(5-10x)\x00*x+10=20'`.

Comment: Now I get `'(\\1*(5-10x))+10=20'`, with `\\1` in the result.

Comment: I don't know what's the difference between your Python and mine. I tested in the terminal in Linux Mint 17.

Comment: Ah, then I guess your terminal turns the double backslash into a single backslash, so the double backslash doesn't even reach Python. Do you see the misbehaviour in the Python interpreter, IDLE, or if you write it in a file and execute that? I do for all three of those.